# Bottom overflowed even when using singleChildScrollView LIstview.bulder

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a list in a flutter app. Here is my body:

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          date,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.teal,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: people.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 6.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () => {},
                    title: Text(
                      "Name: "+people[index]['name'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 21
                        ),
                      ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "Phone number: "+people[index]['phone'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 16
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ) 
              ),
            );
            },
        ),
        )  
      ],
    )
),
```

As you see I am using as the root widget of my body. This container has a column child that includes a text which is a header of the page and a `SingleChildScrollView` that will help the lists to be scroll able. I was expecting to get a the list which can be scrolled through but the bottom is being overflowed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can remove the singleChildScrollView, ListView's are scrollable by default

Comment: `SingleChildScrollView` with `ListView.builder` makes little sense

Comment: @AhmedKhattab It's something I tried to when the 'Listview.builder' didn't work alone

Comment: @pskink I removed it and it's still not working

Comment: wrap the Listview.builder in a  `Expanded` widget insted of `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @AbdulazizYesuf can you vote for my answer, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your Lisview inside a Expanded widget insted of a SingleChildScrollView

```
Expanded(
child: ListView.builder()
 )
```

you need to do so because ListView takes every available space, so in order to limit its size(width n height), you need to wrap in in an Expanded widget.

FYI,`Expanded` widgets only work inside Column or row

Answer (score 1):

wrap Listview inside an Expanded widget

```dart
Expanded(
child: ListView.builder()
 )
```

or use Container and set the height and width

Answer (score 0):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` as the root widget. For example :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child : Container(....)
  );
}
```